# Correct xml escaping in Java

Tags: java, xml, stringescapeutils

I need to convert CSV into XML and then to OutputStream. Rule is to convert `"` into `&quot;` in my code.

Input CSV row:

```
{"Test":"Value"}
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
<child>{&quot;Test&quot;:&quot;Value&quot;}</child>
<root>
```

Current output:

```
<root>
<child>{&amp;quot;Test&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;Value&amp;quot;}</child>
<root>
```

Code:

```
File file = new File(FilePath);
BufferedReader reader = null;

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document newDoc = domBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("root");
newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);

reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String text = null;

    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Element rowElement = newDoc.createElement("child");
            rootElement.appendChild(rowElement);
            text = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(text);
            rowElement.setTextContent(text);
            }

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(newDoc);
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()))
```

Could you please help? What I miss and when `&` convert to `&amp;`?

Comment: You are double-escaping. DOM will escape for you, but you escape too. Remove call to `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(text)`.

Comment: I've read about this. Strange is That after removing escaping, there are no escape happen at all.

Comment: Because you only need to escape `"` in attributes with values quoted by `"`, e.g. this is valid XML: `<test foo="he'd said: &quot;Hello&quot;" bar='he&apos;d said: "Hello"'>he'd said: "Hello"</test>`. The characters `<` and `&` must always be quoted (except in CDATA), while `>` only needs quoting when following `]]` (as in the CDATA terminator `]]>`), but `>` is usually always quoted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML library will automatically escape strings that need to be XML-escaped, so you don't need to manually escape using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml`. Simply remove that line and you should get <s>exactly what you're looking for</s> properly-escaped XML.

XML doesn't require `"` characters to be escaped everywhere, only within attribute values. So this is valid XML already:

```
<root>
<child>{"Test":"Value"}</child>
<root>
```

You would escape the quotes if you had an attribute that contained a quote, such as: `<child attr="properly &quot;ed"/>`

This is one of the main reasons to use an XML library: the subtleties of quoting are already handled for you. No need to read the [XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) to make sure you got the quoting rules correct.

Comment: I've read about this. Strange is That after removing escaping, there are no escape happen at all.

Comment: @user3305630: Updated the answer based on your comment